# condensing the gap between flutter bottom navigation bar widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have been trying to make the flutter bottom navigation bar widget to condense the gap between icons.

[image]

How would I be able to do this. I am imagining that I would need to create my own bottom navigation bar but if there is a simpler solution then I am all ears.

Thank you.

Comment: One thing on top of my head, why not try adding some transparent fake Icons on the left and right?

Comment: that's not a bad idea actually. But what do you mean by fake icons. I'm not sure if that would work as they would still be pressable no?

Comment: Ah yes it looks like you can't disable them as they'd still show an ink animation, I guess your best bet is to go for a custom navigation bar as there doesn't seem to be a direct intuitive way to achieve what you want by using the BottomNavigation bar as is currently.

Comment: it does look like that yeah. plus I can't assign any other widget to the items list

Comment: Yes the Items list only allows you to use the NavigationBarItem which isn't flexible at all

Comment: is there an issue for this. perhaps they developers can look into it. although I suppose it wouldn't make sense to have any widget in the list. maybe some gap parameter would be better

Answer (score 1):

Okay seems like I was being silly.

You can add padding to a specific side to get it moving like so:

```dart
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Container(
    child: Icon(Icons.explore),
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 0, 0, 0),
    ),
  title: Text("Explore"),
),
```